# Rollup plugin typescript generate nested src directory inside dist for declaration

Tags: typescript, rollup

My folder structure

```
| - rollup.config.ts
| - tsconfig.json
| - src
| - - index.ts
```

My build script `rollup --config rollup.config.ts --configPlugin @rollup/plugin-typescript`

Rollup config

```
import { RollupOptions } from 'rollup'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import typescriptModule from 'typescript'
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete'

const RollupConfig: RollupOptions = {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/index.js',
        format: 'cjs',
    },
    plugins: [
        del({ targets: 'dist/*' }),
        typescript({
            typescript: typescriptModule,
            outDir: 'dist',
            declarationDir: 'dist',
            declaration: true,
            sourceMap: true,
        }),
    ],
}
export default RollupConfig
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "include": ["src", "rollup.config.ts"]
}
```

When I run the build command it generate

```
| - dist
| - - index.js
| - - rollup.config.d.ts
| - - src
| - - - index.d.ts
```

But I want the declaration to be inside dist and without the `rollup.config.ts`

```
| - dist
| - - index.js
| - - index.d.ts
```

### Edit

If I remove `rollup.config.ts` from my tsconfig includes it will throw error

```
[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
rollup.config.ts (6:18)
4: import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete'
5:
6: const RollupConfig: RollupOptions = {
                     ^
7:   input: 'src/index.ts',
8:   output: {
    at error (node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:353:30)
    at Module.error (node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15206:16)       
    at Module.tryParse (node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15937:25)    
    at Module.setSource (node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15538:39)   
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:25720:20)
```

Comment: If you don't want to include the rollup config why is it in `"include"`? For the declarations did you try not overriding the directory, they're usually siblings of the files they describe by default.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I remove the `rollup.config.ts` from `include` in `tsconfig.json` it will throw error `[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the `@rollup/plugin-typescript` options

Add `exclude: ['rollup.config.ts']`

Final `rollup.config.ts`

```
import { RollupOptions } from 'rollup'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import typescriptModule from 'typescript'
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete'

const RollupConfig: RollupOptions = {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/index.js',
        format: 'esm',
    },
    plugins: [
        del({ targets: 'dist/*' }),
        typescript({
            typescript: typescriptModule,
            outDir: 'dist',
            declarationDir: 'dist',
            declaration: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            exclude: ['rollup.config.ts'],
        }),
    ],
}

export default RollupConfig
```